# Transform icon to a button with Js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

am trying to make this icon as button but it doesn't work

```
//icons buttons
   let bookmark='<a id="bookmarkbutton"><i id="bookmark" class="fas fa-bookmark fa-3x"></i></a>';
   
   let bookmarkbutton= document.getElementById("bookmarkbutton"); 



   
   //bookmark on click function 
       bookmarkbutton.onclick=function() {
        console.log("the button works");
    }
```

here is the link to repository https://github.com/yaminecy/html

Comment: Please just use a button. Please? For the sake of your users.

Comment: Well... did you actually insert `bookmark` into the DOM before attempting to select for it and bind the event listener to it? A better solution will be to create the element using `document.createElement()`, in that sense you can bind event listeners to the node before inserting it.

Comment: I didn't append it to the DOM because it is added in a ul list after an API fetch ``` const livre=document.createElement("div");
    livre.innerHTML= '<div id= "livre"><ul>'+bookmark+title+ id +author+selectdescription+
    selectimg+'</ul></div>';
    capture.appendChild(livre);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first insert the "button" into the DOM. Then you can select it.

```js
let bookmark = '<a id="bookmarkbutton"><i id="bookmark" class="fas fa-bookmark fa-3x"></i></a>';
document.body.innerHTML+=bookmark;

let bookmarkbutton = document.getElementById("bookmarkbutton");

bookmarkbutton.onclick = function() {
  console.log("the button works");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just use jquery

```js
$(document).append($('<a id="bookmarkbutton"><i id="bookmark" class="fas fa-bookmark fa-3x"></i></a>'););
$('#bookmarkbutton').off('click');
$('#bookmarkbutton').on('click', (event)=>{
     console.log("the button works");
});
```

Comment: Please may you not recommend the OP use jQuery when it has not been tagged, nor actually used in the question?

Comment: its clean and simple, jquery is a great tool

Comment: I don't disagree that jquery is useful. It just was not asked for

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having to enter the html before using onclick, I suggest you use:

- `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`
- `cursor:pointer;` css, so you can simulate button

```js
//icons buttons
let bookmark = '<a id="bookmarkbutton"><i id="bookmark" class="fas fa-bookmark fa-3x"></i></a>';
document.body.innerHTML += bookmark;
let bookmarkbutton = document.getElementById("bookmarkbutton");

//bookmark on click function 
bookmarkbutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("the button works");
});
```

```css
i {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
```